# Singularities in conservative vector fields

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem, gradient-flows, curl

I am trying to compute $\oint\limits_C m(x,y) dx + n(x,y) dy$ where $F(x,y)=\langle m(x,y), n(x,y) \rangle = \langle \frac{\cos{(\ln{(xy)})}}{x}, \frac{\cos{(\ln{(xy)})}}{y} \rangle $ and $C$ is the ellipse parameterized by $(x(t),y(t))=(2\cos{(t)}+11, 3\sin{(t)}-15)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$.

I know that $F$ is an irrotational vector field since $\frac{\partial m}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial n}{\partial x}=0$ and since $C$ is a closed curve, by the fundamental theorem of line integrals, this integral should calculate to zero...that is if the curve enclosed no singularities of $F$. I know the singularity at $(0,0)$ doesn't matter for this computation as $C$ doesn't enclose it, but the logarithm will output complex values over the interior of $C$, which leads to hyperbolic cosine outputting complex values over the region.

When I compute this integral directly rather than applying the fundamental theorem of line integrals I *do* get zero. My question is *why?* Can we just ignore the fact that we get complex values over the region, is the term singularity only used to designate complete undefinition (like division by zero), rather than undefinition over the reals? My thought is that we get an "explosion" of the vector field near $(0,0)$ but not at the other points discussed. Is this valid logic?

Comment: When you say "compute it directly", do you mean considering the logarithm as attaining complex values and explicitly evaluating the integrals?

Comment: No, I mean actually integrating the field over the curve by computing $ \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} F(x(t), y(t))\cdot (x'(t),y'(t)) dt $, so evaluating a single line integral rather than computing a double integral of the curl over the region enclosed by the curve.

Comment: Since $x y$ is negative, any branch of the logarithm is complex-valued on $C$. If the branch cut is placed along the positive real axis, then the gradient theorem applies. $F = \sin \ln x y$ is a potential.

As an exercise, suppose we choose a branch s.t. $F$ has a discontinuity at some $l < 0$. (This is possible if the branch cut has common points with the negative real axis but doesn't coincide with it.) The hyperbola $x y = l$ splits the ellipse $C$ into two parts. The integral over the upper part is $F(l + 0) - F(l + 0)$ and the integral over the lower part is $F(l - 0) - F(l - 0)$.